# Adding numbers with different priorities into a total value that does not exceed the allowable

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have an array of numbers, each number has its own priority and price, the price is the value of the number, how to calculate the sum of a set of these numbers in decreasing order of priority so that the sum does not exceed the allowable one, please tell me at least the name of the algorithm with which it is can be done. Example: there are numbers 2, 3, 9 with priorities 3, 1, 2, respectively. The constraint is 4, therefore the number 9 is cut off immediately, since 9> 4, 2 and 3 we cannot add together, since 5> 3, therefore the choice of 2 numbers is 2 and 3, but since the number 2 has a higher priority, we add only his, this algorithm should work with any number of numbers.

Comment: does number of items selected needs to be maximised?

Comment: What needs to be maximised here? The sum?

Comment: Order by priority then adding (or skipping) why meeting the constraint in the process?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm#:%7E:text=Greedy%20algorithms%20produce%20good%20solutions,work%20will%20have%20two%20properties%3A&text=It%20iteratively%20makes%20one%20greedy,algorithm%20never%20reconsiders%20its%20choices.):

1. Order By `priority`
2. Scan this ordered collection from the beginning while
3. Adding item if `total` meets the constrait(s), skipping if constraint is broken.

In your case:

`2, 3, 9` with priorities `3, 1, 2` and a constraint `total <= 4`

After ordering we have

`2, 9, 3`

then we scan:

1. `2` take (`total == 2` meets the constraint)
2. `9` skip (`total == 2 + 9 == 11 > 4` doesn't meet the constraint)
3. `3` skip (`total == 2 + 3 == 5 > 4` doesn't meet the constraint)

So far we should take the only `2` item.

**Edit:** you've dropped `9` since `9 > 4` and that's why `9` can't be in the solution. This process (when we drop items or, on the contrary, take items which are guaranteed to be in the solution) is called [Kernelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernelization#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20kernelization,%2C%20called%20a%20%22kernel%22.)

In *general case* when you *can skip high priority item* in order to take, say, ten low priority items you have [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)